# listview does not work in flutter with widget as its child?

Tags: flutter, listview, widget

Why does this code not work ins flutter? It says it cannot use the 'Listview' with <widget[] as one of its children?

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: ListView(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 30.0),
          children: <widget>[
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, right: 120.0),
                child: Text(
                  'what would you like to find?',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 30.0,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
  }
}
```

Comment: Simply , just remove <widget> . It will work fine . In Flutter , Everything is a widget

Answer (score 0):

We write `Widget` with a capital W .

`Widget` not `widget`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it should be `<Widget>` and not `<widget>`

Also, you don't have to define the children content of a Listview. So just remove `<widget>` alltogether.